# JQuery Datepicker inside a dialog Doesn't update the input value

Tags: jquery, dialog, datepicker

I have created a simple web form inside a dialog. When I bring up the dialog I click inside the datepicker input and the calendar pops up. When I select a date the date picker closes, but the date in the input doesn't actually change.

```
$("#ProductContractEntry").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    hide: { effect: "explode", duration: 500 },
    modal: false,
    width: 'auto',
    height: 'auto',
    position: 
    { 
        my: "left left", 
        at: "left left", 
        of: window, 
        collision: "fit", 
        within: "#mainContent" 
    },
    closeOnEscape: true,
});

$("#Expiration").datepicker();
```

Comment: Can you replicate your problem in a [Fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: I have yet to be able to reproduce it in Fiddle. When I create a really simple example (Seen Below) it always seems to work. I am guessing that it would appear that my more complex mvc page that pulls in multiple forms and partial views mucks things up in some way.

[link](http://jsfiddle.net/f6Tzx/)

Comment: I'm having the same problem with a couple of date picker inside a jQuery dialog in an MVC site. Thing is I have a number of other places where this works - but this time it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Format the original date as `mm/dd/yyyy` instead:

```
<tr><td><input type="text" id="Expiration" value="04/01/2013" class="datepicker" /></td></tr>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/f6Tzx/2/

Answer (score 0):

Also on my page is a jqGrid that had a row with a colmodel name of Expiration as well. Even though I had added an index: "g_Expiration" to the colmodel for that row the ID was conflicting with my input with the ID "Expiration". After I changed the name of the index in the colmodel to "contract_Expiration" it started properly setting the input when the date was selected.